# How to find out what app owns a menu bar item?

Tags: macos, big-sur

One of the items in my menu bar is just blank. Totally transparent. How do I find out which app/program owns it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Accessibility Inspector:

> Apple provides the Accessibility Inspector testing tool that can be launched by choosing Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Accessibility Inspector in the menu bar or Dock. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store for free.

Then you can select the element on screen to get its properties. [Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html) more info.

Once you click on a Menu Item you have to check it's parent element. Here's how it works:

[image: Accessibility Inspector with "show parent" button]

After you click that arrow you can see the app name under Advanced -> Parent.

The item I've selected is BetterTouchTool:

[image: BetterTouchTool as a parent item]

Comment: I don't have xcode

Comment: But you can get it for free: "You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store for free"